# Change a variable when changing screen width (e.g. landscape to portrait)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have am displaying a message from a data base into columns. When viewing on an iPhone (screen size 375 X 812 px) it works.
However when the phone is turned to landscape (812 x375) the amount of columns doesn't change here is the code:

```
<div class="content">
  <table   class="table1"   width="98%">
<?php   $count = '0'; 
      if ($screenwidth < 481){$max_columns =3;}else {                                     
               $max_columns = 4;}
             do { 
                 if ($count < $max_columns){
                 if ($count == 0){
                     echo "<tr>"; 
                               }?>
 
      <td align="center"  class="td1">
                        <div>    <php echo $message ?>
        </div>
      </td>
          
   <?php } else { 
           $count = 0;
           echo "</tr><tr>";?>
          <td  align="center" class="td1">
         <div ><?php echo $message;</div>
       
       <?php echo "</td>";?>                           
              <?php } $count++; } 
       while($row_RS_Search = $RS_Search2->fetch() );
           echo "</tr>"; ?>
     </table></div>
```

Then I am trying to retrieve the screen width as follows:

```
<?php
  $clientProps=array('screen.width','screen.height','window.innerWidth','window.innerHeight', 
    'window.outerWidth',);

  if(! isset($_POST['screenheight'])){

    echo "Loading...<form method='POST' id='data' style='display:none'>";
    foreach($clientProps as $p) {  //create hidden form
      echo "<input type='text' id='".str_replace('.','',$p)."' name='".str_replace('.','',$p)."'>";
    }
    echo "<input type='submit'></form>";

    echo "<script>";
    foreach($clientProps as $p) {  //populate hidden form with screen/window info
      echo "document.getElementById('" . str_replace('.','',$p) . "').value = $p;";
    }
    echo "document.forms.namedItem('data').submit();"; //submit form
    echo "</script>";

  }else{

    foreach($clientProps as $p) {   //create output table
     
    }
      $screenwidth =  $_POST['screenwidth'] ;
      $screenheight =$_POST['screenheight'];
   }
?>
```

This works on loading the page but when the screen is turn the screen with does not change.
I know it is probably the php script however I I not very good with AJAX or Java any help would be appreciated

Comment: PHP is server-side. Use JS or CSS to make layout changes "on the fly"

Comment: @brombeer the problem is I am not sure how to use the JS to change the columns from 3 to 4 when turning the screen. Could you point me in the right direction pls

Comment: As for CSS: [Responsive design](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Responsive_Design) and [Media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries) could be helpful

Comment: @brombeer I tried media only screen and (min-width:481px){ $columns = 4} but that doesn't work as I thought CSS in only for styling unless you hide them, not sure how you would only with overflow:hide but then it will be missing the last messages displayed in the columns on the end not changing the amount of things that are displayed in this case the amount of columns.

Comment: My fault, I ignored the fact that you are using a `<table>`, sorry. Do you use the table for layout? (nono) Or is there content in every single column?

Comment: @brombeer the content is pulled from a DB so depending on how many rows each <td> will have the $message displayed. The $message is styled with CSS it is just the amount of column that are displayed I want to change when the screen changes width e.g from portrait to landscape. So when it is portrait I want 3Columns displayed when landscape 4. I was hoping that the code above would have explained that. Where the $screenwidth in mentioned.